# Cannot build Corona SDK project: Code signing identity says, "Certificate not installed"

Tags: xcode, provisioning, keychain, coronasdk

I'm working with the Corona SDK and need some help setting up my provisioning profiles properly to get my project to build.  I had previously succeeded in setting up my app, my devices, my provisioning profile, and had the app build properly.  Then one day, *poof* - it stopped working.  Most people say, "Uninstall everything then try again." which I did a number of times, but still no luck.  I cataloged every step I took in hopes that someone on stackoverflow could help me out.

I attempted to setup my provisioning profiles two different ways.  The first, by following Corona SDK's documentation found here: http://developer.coronalabs.com/demo/DeviceBuildGuide.pdf.  At the end of this attempt, I could not select the code signing identity from within Corona's build tool.  It said, "Certificate not installed."  This was probably due to the fact that I may have not had my private key of the certificate installed.  I repeated Corona's steps a few times but the private keys never appeared in Keychain Access.

On my second attempt, I took a different route: I cleared out my provisioning profiles from both the Mac and from the Apple developer's portal and tried just refreshing my Provisioning Profiles from within XCode's Organizer window.  Still no luck, but this time I got an error when trying to build in Corona, "Disallowed signer..."

Here's a step by step recount of what I've tried, including screen captures:

**ATTEMPT #1**

First, I wiped out everything related to provisioning that I know how to. Here's my Keychain Access manager after having cleaned everything out:

[image]

I also made sure that all files were cleared out of /Users/(your user)/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/. At this point, when I try to build in Corona, nothing is listed under "Code Signing Identity":

[image]

Looks pretty clean. So, next I start following Corona's build tutorial (http://developer.coronalabs.com/demo/DeviceBuildGuide.pdf). First step: Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority:

[image]

Everything went fine. Next, time to get my new Development Certificate:

[image]

After downloading and double clicking my certificate, the Keychain Access window opened and looked like this:

[image]

I'm assuming this is all correct. My device is already added to my Apple Development account, and I already have an App ID. My app's name recently changed, but I was pretty sure that I successfully built with the new name. I only changed the name in Corona. I didn't modify the App ID or anything strange.

I now created both a Development and Distribution profile.

[image]

...

As you can see, an old Invalid provisioning profile existed called "BT Dev Prov Prof". Once I created my new profile, I was able to remove the old Invalid profile

And I did the same for the distribution profile.

I downloaded the distribution profile and copied it to /Users/(your user)/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/

And finally, attempted to build again in Corona:

[image]

No luck.

It's worth noting, too, that my provisioning profile when viewed in XCODE says, "Valid Signing identity not found":

[image]

I've tried one more thing which didn't make any difference - I added Apple's root certificates to my keychain:

[image]

**ATTEMPT #2**

My second attempt involved clearing out all the provisioning stuff from both Apple and the Mac and letting XCode try to download and install everything for me.  Here's the step-by-step of that attempt:

First, I cleared everything out of XCode, The Keychain Access, and revoked my development and distribution certificates from the Apple developer portal:

[image]

Then I clicked Refresh in XCode's Provisioning Profiles and was prompted to enter my login info:

[image]

XCode then told me I had no iOS Development Certificate or iOS Distribution certificate. I asked it both times to request one on my behalf:

[image]

Once it was finished, it showed me the developer provisioning profile, but it still said that "Valid signing identity not found":

[image]

But in the keychan access tool, things looked better:

[image]

So, I decided to try building my app...and (drum roll please)...

[image]

Ouch, still no luck!

Any help would be much appreciated.

- Bret

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem at the moment. I have the certificate, have the prov profiles, and yet Corona and Xcode both say "Valid signing identity not found"